# How to change coordinates using pinlabel on Overleaf?

Tags: labels, svg

I am trying to use `pinlabel` to label a SVG file on Overleaf. I have included `\usepackage{pinlabel}`, and I am trying to follow the `pinlabel` documentation, but whenever I change coordinates, my text does not move on the image.

Here is the code I have to get the text on the image (along with the other packages in use):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgpath{{../imgs/}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pinlabel}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \small\hair 2pt
    \pinlabel $\mathbb{R}^2$ at 0 0
    \centering
    \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width=350pt]{Figure 14}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the resulting image:
[image]

I saw on the documentation to include `\labellist` before the labels, but whenever I do that I get a pretty gnarly error. I think that might just be an Overleaf problem, but I am not sure.

No matter what coordinates I try, the text does not move.

**EDIT:**

After applying some suggestions, I am getting a weird output. If I use:

```
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \labellist
    \small\hair 2pt
    \pinlabel $\mathbb{R}^2$ at 400 400
    \endlabellist
    \centering
    \includesvg[inkscapelatex=false, width=300pt]{Figure 14}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

I get
[image]

If I use (removing `inkscapelatex=false`)

```
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \labellist
    \small\hair 2pt
    \pinlabel $\mathbb{R}^2$ at 400 400
    \endlabellist
    \centering
    \includesvg[width=300pt]{Figure 14}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

I get

[image]

(The little thing at the bottom does not move when I change the coordinates.)

Could this be an error from using SVG files?

Comment: Please always post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to make things easier for people willing to help you, and to clarify what exact environment you're working in. Thank you.

Comment: I am confused what else I need to add. I mentioned that I am working in Overleaf, the image is of type SVG, and am using the package pinlabel, and I included the code and the resulting image. @Miyase

Comment: It's explained in the link I gave. If you're new to LaTeX, you might not know that a lot depends on the packages you're using and the interactions between them, and sometimes also on the class or compiler you're using. Another reason is simply out of politeness for the people able to help you, to give them a code that they can copy-paste and test directly, without having to guess what you didn't type.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought I had it. My understanding of the link you provided was only to have the minimal amount necessary. I have added some edits that hopefully are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place `\labellist` before and `\endlabellist` after the `\pinlabel` macros (look into the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pinlabel/pinlabdoc.pdf) for more information):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pinlabel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \labellist                             % <- !
    \small\hair 2pt
    \pinlabel $\mathbb{R}^2$ at 120 220
    \endlabellist                          % <- !
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=350pt]{example-image-a}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It is not an error specific to Overleaf but it is just how this package works. Without the two macros `\labellist` before and `\endlabellist`, you will get a strange output or errors such as these two small equals signs at the top of the picture.

---

Sadly, however, the `pinlabel` package is not compatible with the `svg` package. You can use the `overpic` package instead which accepts arbitrary contents to attach labels to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{Overpic}{\includesvg[width=300pt]{Figure 14}}
        \put(30,50){$\mathbb{R}^2$}
    \end{Overpic}
    \caption{...}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I applied your suggestions and have a new problem. I included it as an edit on my original post. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: You are right. It seems that `pinlabel` is not compatible with the `svg` package. So, you either need to convert your SVG to EPS and include this via `\includegraphics` or you need to use another way to place the labels onto the SVG. =(

Comment: Ah, how lame. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The package `pinlabel` relies on the original definition of `\includegraphics` but package `svg` needs to patch this command in order to get the invocation of Inkscape done. A proper workaround would be to use package `svg-extract` and initially export the SVG image to PDF format and include the result via `\includegraphics` afterwards.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{svg-extract}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pinlabel}

\newcommand*\includeextractedsvg[2][]{%
  \includesvg[exclude,extractname=#2]{#2}%
  \includegraphics[#1]{svg-extract/#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \labellist
  \small\hair 2pt
  \pinlabel $\mathbb{R}^2$ at 40 40
  \endlabellist
  \centering
  \includeextractedsvg[width=300pt]{svg-example}%
  \caption{...}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result after the *second* run is attached.

[image: svg-extract and pinlabel]